# how to detect mysql database connection failure in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using the latest 2.1.4 version of codeigniter and am using mysql database.

I am using the codeigniter db API facilities such as query() _error_message() and _error_Numner() to execute and check the db operations.

However I came across a situation where I wanted to check for a failure scenario where I wanted to check how my code behaves if the database is shut down ( mysql service stop). If I invoke my controller/models after shutting down the mysql, I realized that the query( ) API for an insert does not return anything ( its blank).

I was earlier checking for a true or false in case of Insert and empty string in case of select queries but I am interested to know if there can be a way such that I can catch an exception if the db failed to initialize due to connection problem.

I know that CI does not throw an error in case of query execution failure so is it the same case with db connection failure as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request to CodeIgniter backend will fail as soon as CI figure out that MySQL server is down. You can just write some additional info to user on the error page. Never mind if your function calls the model or not, because CI core functions will always check for MySQL connection.

Anyway, you could try something like this:

```
if (shell_exec('mysql -V') != ''){
  echo "MySql is running";
}else{
  echo "Oooops....";
}
```

Good luck with this on shared hosting. :)